# Error: msvcr80.dll not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I've created a simple Win32 console application. When I try to debug it, I get the message:
 "This application has failed to start because MSVCR80D.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem."

The Release version runs fine.

Any idea as to what the problem could be?

Comment: That's the Visual Studio 2005 debug runtime.  Was this a brand new project?  Did you have VS 2005 on your machine at some point and uninstall it?

Comment: Yes its a new project.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could just copy the msvcr80.dll or msvcr80d.dll into you C:\window\system32\ folder. This may not be the prettiest way to solve it tho.

Comment: This is really *not* a good idea - the dependencies should be identified and corrected if necessary and the correct debug runtimes installed. Just copying DLLs to a system-owned folder is bad practice.